# Are all prime ideals in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ of the form $\langle c, a + b \sqrt{-5} \rangle$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Where $a, b, c \in \mathbb Z$?

I know that if in an UFD, $\langle c, a + b \sqrt{d} \rangle$ would boil down to a principal ideal. But it seems to me that in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, for any purely real integer $c$ that is irreducible, the ideal $\langle c \rangle$ can be properly contained in some suitable choice of $\langle c, a + b \sqrt{-5} \rangle$ that is itself properly contained within the ring.

Comment: I think it's yes.  I believe there is a theorem that says in a Dedekind domain that all ideals can be generated by at most  two elements.

Comment: But that might not necessarily rule out an ideal like $\langle a + b \sqrt{-5} \rangle$ being prime...

Comment: Yes but we know it's not a PID

Comment: @user26857 I feel this edit changes the meaning. See the comment of OP. The main concern seems to be if the phrase starting with "But" is true or not.

Comment: @quid I don't think 26857's edit was an improvement but I don't think it changed the meaning. I would characterize it more as a stylistic imposition.

Comment: @quid I retract that last comment now that I see how David was thrown off.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Then $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ and hence principal, take $I \cap \mathbb{Z} = (c)$. Then, **as abelian groups**, $I/c \mathbb{Z}$ injects into $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Let the image be generated by the coset $\mathbb{Z}+b \sqrt{-5}$ and lift this coset to $a+b \sqrt{-5}$ in $I$. Then $a+b \sqrt{-5}$ and $c$ generate $I$ as an abelian group and, therefore, as an ideal.

Comment: I feel this does not answer the question, which is in my understadning rather if it is always *necessary* to have two elements.  See the body of the question and the comment.

Comment: @quid It definitely answers the question in the quote box. The OP's comments after that leave me a little confused, though. Possibly, he or she doesn't understand that an ideal can have many different generating sets? EG $\langle 1+\sqrt{-5} \rangle = \langle 2, 1+\sqrt{-5} \rangle$, so this ideal is both of the form $\langle a+b \sqrt{-5}, c \rangle$ and $\langle d+e \sqrt{-5} \rangle$.

Comment: The quoted box is there since 5 minutes only and not due to OP.  The question is in my reading if there *exist* (nonzero) pinicipal prime ideals (the OP thinking they do not exist).

Comment: If John-Luke knows about "disguised" principal ideals in PIDs, surely he knows about different generators, e.g., $\langle 12, 20 \rangle$ for $\langle 4 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, and that principal ideals can be similarly disguised in non-PIDs.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you about different generating sets in general, but I'm confused by your example of $\langle 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle = \langle 2, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$. Since $N(1 + \sqrt{-5}) = 6$, how can $\langle 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$ contain numbers of norm 4?

Comment: @RobertSoupe You're absolutely right, oops! $\langle 1+\sqrt{-5} \rangle = \langle 6, 1+\sqrt{-5} \rangle$, not what I wrote.

Answer (score 5):

A Dedekind domain $\,D\,$ satisfies what's known as the $\,1\ 1/2\,$ (one and a half) generator property: given an ideal $\,I\subset D\,$ and  $\,0\neq i\in I\,$ then  there is some $\,j\in I\,$ such that $\,I = (i,j).\,$

For example, if $\, (n) = I\cap \Bbb Z\,$ then $\, I = (n,w)\,$ for some $\,w,\, $ as you seek.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not the case that for any irreducible integer $c$ the principal ideal $(c)$ is *properly* contained in an $(c, a + b \sqrt{-5})$ that is properly contained in the full ring.

If $p$ is a prime number number that is [inert](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376590/vague-definitions-of-ramified-split-and-inert-in-a-quadratic-field) in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ then essentially by definition $(p)$ is a prime ideal in  $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Now, as a Dedekind domain $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is one-dimensional and thus each non-zero prime ideal is maximal. Thus for an inert prime $p$ the ideal $(p)$ is not properly contained in any ideal but the full ring.

As explained in other answers it is possible to write every ideal in the form $(c, a + b \sqrt{-5})$, and in particular $(p)$, in the form $(p, a + b \sqrt{-5})$, but in the case I mention there is no *proper* containment.

It is also true that every prime ideal of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ contains some prime number and thus the principal ideal $(p)$ for some prime number $p$. Thus, if you drop the condition that $(p)$ is *properly* contained in $(p, a + b \sqrt{-5})$ then (but only then) what you say seems to be true is in fact true.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, I think it's the one the OP will accept. But, for the sake of less algebraically sophisticated people like me, could you give a concrete example? Such as take $13$, which is definitely irreducible in this ring, and maybe also prime. If $\langle 13 \rangle$ is a prime ideal, then any $\langle 13, a + b \sqrt{-5} \rangle$ turns out to be the whole ring, right?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Indeed, $13$ is inert as it does not divide the disrimianant, i.e. $-20$, and $-5$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $13$, that is $-5$ cannot be written as $a^2$ modulo $13$. However, it is not exactly true that $(13, a + b \sqrt{-5})$ is the full ring for every choice of $a,b$. If $a=b=0$ or $a=b=13$ or $a= 13, b=-26$ and so on, then this ideal is just $(13)$. It is however true for any $a + b \sqrt{-5}$ outside $(13)$ that is not divisible by $13$.

Comment: So any choice of $a \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$ and likewise for $b$ makes $\langle 13, a + b \sqrt{-5} \rangle = \langle 13 \rangle$ and otherwise $\langle 13, a + b \sqrt{-5} \rangle = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$?

Comment: Yes. $a+b\sqrt{-15}$ is a mulitple of $13$ if and only if both $a$ and $b$ are multiples of $13$. In this case the ideal is unchanged. Otherwise it is the full ring.